# Add article markup in database

Tags: html, wysiwyg

I am creating a CMS (IN ASP) and I add some content via my CMS into the database.

But I am going to use a WYSIWYG-editor. So I can markup my content with using colours, making some words bold etc.

But how can I save the markup which I made with the WYSIWYG-editor into the database?

**For example:**

I want to save this article with my WYSIWYG-editor(with "name" as bold):

Hello my **name** is Mike.

Do I need to save this as below in the database:

`Hello my <b>name</b> is Mike.`

Or how do I need to save content that contains markup? Because I must be able to retrieve the content from the database and show the articles with the markup they contain on the website.

EDIT: I'm using MySQL

Comment: This is a reasonable question, why the votes to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with saving markup and content together in the database.

Just be sure to use the correct datatype and set a reasonable char limit, something like `varchar(5000)` depending on the column and what the data is being used for obviously.

**How** you save this to the database will be down to the DBMS you're using, which you haven't specified

Comment: Are you looking for specific code to insert these values into your database?

Comment: No, I just want to add some content with markup in the database, but will the WYSIWYG-editor create the tags like <b> <i> <color> etc. by hisself? And if I get the articles from the database, will ASP convert the <b> tags etc. automatically to their original markup look?

Comment: I can't speak for every WYSIWYG editor out there but I know that FCKEditor/CKEditor does. I would imagine that they behave in a similar way, so a reluctant **yes** would be my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial thought is correct, you need to store your article together with the markup in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new table called 'ContentFormatting' with these columns:

FormattingId (PK)
Word
FormatType

For example you would have this entry for 'name':

> FormattingId (PK): 1 Word: "name" FormatType: "bold"

When you display in ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblArticle" Text='<%# FormatArticle(Eval("xyzArticle")) %>' />
```